# IntelliJ validation support for javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javadoc

Eclipse offers the ability to customize it in order to show missing and malformed javadocs comments and tags besides other related javadoc problems as well as the visibility of each class aspect to be scanned in problems view as shown below:

[image: Javadoc configuration in Eclipse]
[image: Problems Eclipse view reporting javadoc issues]

Are there any alternatives that achieve the same goals for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA can highlight Javadoc problem if you enable the relevant inspections under `Preferences | Editor | Inspections`. You want to take a look at the `Java | Javadoc` section in the inspection tree.